Column sort in Rally Custom App working on some columns but not others
Trying to make a basic custom app (source code taken from Rally examples page) column sort work. Column sorting is active for all the columns in the code below, but will only actually sort for ID, Name, and Schedule State. Iteration, Release, and Owner are all clickable but will not sort.
How to make all the columns sort on click?
        Ext.define('Rally.example.SimpleTreeGrid', {
            extend: 'Rally.app.App',
            componentCls: 'app',
        
            launch: function() {
                Ext.create('Rally.data.wsapi.TreeStoreBuilder').build({
                    models: ['defect'],
                    autoLoad: true,
                    enableHierarchy: true
                }).then({
                    success: this._onStoreBuilt,
                    scope: this
                });
            },
        
            _onStoreBuilt: function(store) {
                this.add({
                    xtype: 'rallytreegrid',
                    store: store,
                    context: this.getContext(),
                    enableEditing: false,
                    enableBulkEdit: false,
                    shouldShowRowActionsColumn: false,
                    enableRanking: false,
                    columnCfgs: [
                        'Name',                            
                        'ScheduleState',
                        'Iteration',
                        'Owner',
                        'Project'
                    ]
                });
            }
        });
        

        Rally.launchApp('Rally.example.SimpleTreeGrid', {
          name: 'Simple Tree Grid Example'
        });

Tried all the various properties and methods from the documentation, nothing works.
